# Hystrix when set timeout, dont change it

Tags: java, spring, hystrix

i have a problem with timeout hystrix.
I know that hystrix has a timeout of 1 second and I want to increase it, but when I modify it in my application.properties the properties are still 1 second and not to increase it.

application.properties

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.strategy = THREAD
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled = true
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds = 30000
hystrix.command.default.circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds = 60000
logging.level.com.netflix.hystrix = debug
```

MyAppApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableScheduling
public class MyAppApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyAppApplication.class, args);        
    }

}
```

MyAppService.java

```
@Service
public class MyAppService{
   @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "myMethodFallback",
            ignoreExceptions = {AxisFault.class, MalformedURLException.class, JAXBException.class, 
   MailException.class})
   public OutputDto myMethod(InputDto input){
     return anotherService.method(input);
   }

   public OutputDto myMethodFallback(InputDto input){
     return anotherService.methodFallback(input);
   }
}
```